# Automatic reindex of @IndexedEmbedded field

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

As far I can understand from reading this part of the documentation of

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-basics

there's no automatic reindexing on @IndexedEmbedded fields that doesn't have a bidirectional mapping. Am I correct? And if so I'm curious to know what leaded to introduce this, because in Hibernate search automatic reindexing happened when updating a field in an @IndexedEmbedded field. Does this mean that now I'm responsible to update the index?

Here's an example of my use case which leads to a not updated index:

```
@Indexed(index = "foo_index")
@Entity
public class Foo {

   private Long id;

   @IndexedEmbedded
   @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
   private Bar bar;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
   private Long id;

   @GenericField
   private String barFieldOne;

   @GenericField
   private String barFieldTwo;
}
```

Then let's say I retrieve the Foo from the db and change a bar field like this:

```
Foo foo = repository.findById(1);
foo.getBar().setBarFieldOne("newValue");
repository.save(foo);
```

This will not trigger index update of the foo index despite I'm working through the @Indexed object(Foo in our case). I have a lot of uni directional relations and I don't want to make them bidirectional because I don't need them and they can lead to performance problems. I understand that if I update the bar entity by itself it won't update the index but here I'm updating it through the main @Indexed entity and I expect the index to be updated.

This use case worked flawlessly in hibernate search 5 and in my honest opinion this is an important. Is there a way to make it work here, because this will make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You understood well, Hibernate Search cannot trigger reindexing when there's just an unidirectional association between the modified entity and the indexed entity.

There are plans to address that, maybe, one day, but that will still require some configuration: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1937

> This use case worked flawlessly in hibernate search 5 and in my honest opinion this is an important

I'm going to need a reproducer for that. I would be very, very surprised if you managed to make it work. **If** it worked, it was probably just a side-effect of something else: you disabled dirty checking, or you had a transient property on your entity that caused it to be reindexed every single time.

All we did in Search 6 was to make sure we throw an error when you try to use `@IndexedEmbedded` on an uni-directional association, and force you to explicitly disable automatic reindexing for that association.

It didn't work in Hibernate Search 5 either, but Hibernate Search 5 would ignore these problems silently and you would end up *thinking* it worked, but it did not.

So really, the only change is that you are now aware of the problem. It existed before.

Comment: As I'm still in the process of migrating from version 5 to 6(and I have really big codebase related to hibernate search) I'm running my application tests and now they fail because of not updating IndexedEmbedded field. I'm pretty sure that repository.save(indexedEntity) triggered update of the index even if only IndexedEmbedded field state is changed. My application is strongly dependent on  elasticsearch and believe me I would have understood if IndexedEmbedded fields were not updated in the index.

Comment: The thing is, as someone who's been working on the Hibernate Search codebase on a daily basis for the past few years, I don't know how it could have worked, unless something else (a change on the indexed entity itself) triggered reindexing. If you can write a reproducer that works with Search 5 but not with 6, I'll gladly have a look, but right now I just don't know how it could work. See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search for project templates.